# The meta link on the top banner (private beta) is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta

When a site enters private beta (and for a little while in public beta) there is a notice at the top of the site pointing users to their meta support site.

[image]

This link points to `meta.sitename`.

Since all of the `meta.*.stackexchange.com` sites have moved to `*.meta.stackexchange.com`, the new sites becoming private beta from Area 51 need to have this notice content and the URL updated as per the new change.

In plain text:

> got a question about the site itself? [meta.devops](http://meta.devops.stackexchange.com) is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The URL in the system banner will be updated for new site launches going forward. Thank you for pointing that out.